# Saving value of EditText in SharedPrefences after Text is changed

Tags: java, android, database, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save the data of my EditText `topic` automatically after it'S changed, but I get is this logcat

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.barryblack.FragmentPage0.onCreateView(FragmentPage0.java:68)`

So heres the code the problem is on

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity());

    topic = view.findViewById(R.id.topicText0);

    topic.setText(prefs.getString("autosave", ""));
    topic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            prefs.edit().putString("autosave", s.toString()).apply();

        }
    });
```

And this is my whole code if needed(the `loadData()`  and `SaveDate()` are a method i made to save ArarayList but has nothing to do with my problem)

```
package com.example.barryblack;



public class FragmentPage0 extends Fragment {

private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
private EditText editTask;
private Button insertbtn;
private TextView taskText;

private String task;


Context context;
ArrayList<MyItem> items;


private static final String SHARED_PREFS_FRAGMENT_A = "fragmentA";

private EditText topic;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    CreateExampleList();


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment1, container, false);




    loadData();

    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity());

    topic = view.findViewById(R.id.topicText0);

    topic.setText(prefs.getString("autosave", ""));
    topic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            prefs.edit().putString("autosave", s.toString()).apply();

        }
    });




    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    new 
ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(500);
    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    taskText = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
    insertbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.button_insert);
    editTask = view.findViewById(R.id.editTask);


    context = getActivity();


    insertbtn.setEnabled(false);
    editTask.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
count) {

            String taskInput = editTask.getText().toString().trim();
            insertbtn.setEnabled(!taskInput.isEmpty());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            task = editTask.getText().toString().trim();

        }
    });


    insertbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InsertItem();
            SaveData();
            editTask.setText(null);


        }
    });


    return view;
}


private void SaveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FRAGMENT_A, 
MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(items);
    editor.putString("task list", json);
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FRAGMENT_A, 
MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyItem>>() {
    }.getType();
    items = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (items == null) {
        items = new ArrayList();
    }

}

 public void InsertItem() {

    items.add(new MyItem(task));
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size());
    SaveData();


}

private void CreateExampleList() {
    items = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
}


ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new 
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | 
ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) 
{
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int 
direction) {
        items.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        SaveData();

    }
};

}
```

Comment: `topic = view.findViewById(R.id.topicText0);` should before `topic.setText`

Comment: Also, consider using ViewBinding insted of findViewById.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these:

```
topic.setText(prefs.getString("autosave", ""));
topic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        prefs.edit().putString("autosave", s.toString()).apply();

    }
});
```

directly under this line:

```
topic = view.findViewById(R.id.topicText0);
```

Comment: I literally copied everything and still the same. I get an error because of  `topic.setText(prefs.getString(..)` and thisis my logcat  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.barryblack.FragmentPage0.onCreateView(FragmentPage0.java:71)`          I am gonna update my question so you can see wher I am at right now. Maybe that helps.

Comment: add the xml code of the fragment that contains the edit text.

Comment: ass? Do you mean pass

Comment: Haha, okay I did

Comment: Look when I told you to paste the code under `topic = view.findViewById(R.id.topicText0);` this means you must delete the ones above.

Comment: Yeah but I did it goes like. Or what do you mean with the code above. Im really starting to get confused here

Comment: Wait... I am literally the most stup human alive. I was using the id topictext0 on fragment1  instead of fragment 0. thats what caused the problem. I am still gonna mark you answer as right. Thank you alot

Comment: I just wanted to say that now :)

Answer (score 0):

When you reference `topic`, the variable is not yet instantiated.

You have to put `topic = view.findViewById(R.id.topicText0)` before `topic.setText(prefs.getString("autosave", ""))`.

EDIT: Add a `onViewCreated` method to your fragment and move all your code from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated`, like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment1, container, false);
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // move your code here
    topic = view.findViewById(R.id.topicText0);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I literally copied everything and still the same. I get an error because of topic.setText(prefs.getString(..) and thisis my logcat java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.example.barryblack.FragmentPage0.onCreateView(FragmentPage0.java:71) I am gonna update my question so you can see wher I am at right now. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**topic** is not intialized. 
First intialize the variable

```
topic = view.findViewById(R.id.topicText0);
```

then set the text to view

```
topic.setText(prefs.getString("autosave", ""));
```

and then add change listener

```
topic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            prefs.edit().putString("autosave", s.toString()).apply();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I literally copied everything and still the same. I get an error because of topic.setText(prefs.getString(..) and thisis my logcat java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.example.barryblack.FragmentPage0.onCreateView(FragmentPage0.java:71) I am gonna update my question so you can see wher I am at right now. Maybe that helps.